# MFMessageComposeViewController + SwiftUI Buggy Behavior

Tags: swiftui, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, uiviewrepresentable, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I'm using ViewControllerRepresentable to present a MFMessageComposeViewController so users can send texts from my app.

However, every time the view is presented, it's very buggy - elements randomly disappear, scrolling is off, and the screen flickers. Tested on iOS 14.2 and 14.3.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MessageUI

struct MessageView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var recipient: String
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
        var completion: () -> Void
        init(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
            self.completion = completion
        }
        
        // delegate method
        func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            completion()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator() {} // not using completion handler
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MFMessageComposeViewController {
        let vc = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        vc.recipients = [recipient]

        vc.messageComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMessageComposeViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MFMessageComposeViewController
}
```

and my view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingMessages = false
    @State var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Messages") {
                self.isShowingMessages = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isShowingMessages) {
            MessageView(recipient: "+15555555555")
        }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm presenting this view? Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Similar behavior happens with MFMailComposeViewController, but it's not as buggy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

5 minutes later, I realized I needed to add this when presenting the sheet:

```
MessageView(recipient: "+15555555555")
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```

The view looked buggy because it was trying to account for the keyboard safe area and had a hard time doing it.

Comment: Still not works for me. `Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.`