# Does SwiftUI have a native way to compose SMS messages like MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: swiftui

The title is the whole question.

Google and Apple docs do not provide any indication that there is a native way, but I wanted to triple check with the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no SwiftUI/MessageUI integration as of iOS 17 (currently in beta). You will need to wrap `MFMessageComposeViewController` in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. You may find [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660858/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-swiftui-buggy-behavior) helpful.